# Dojo.toJson() method return "null" string

Tags: dojox.grid, dojox.grid.datagrid, dojo

Here we convert dijit.form.TextBox to json format using dojo.toJson. Without any input it returns "null" which we expect to be "".

Source code are as follows:

//aspx code

```
<input id="name" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.TextBox" data-dojo-props="name:'name'" />
<button id="submitButton" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button" type="button">
    submit</button>
```

//js code

```
define("views/Test", [
    "dojo",
    "dojo/parser",
    "dijit/form/Form",
    "dijit/form/TextBox",
    "dijit/form/Button"
], function () {
    dojo.declare("views.Test", null, {

        onSubmitClick: function () {
            var jsonData = dojo.toJson(dijit.byId("name").get("value")); // here: dijit.byId("name").get("value") is "" and jsonData is ""null""
        },

        startup: function () {
            dojo.connect(dijit.byId("submitButton"), "onClick", this, this.onSubmitClick);
        }
    });
    return views.Test;
});
```

is there any difference between the following two? since the result is not the same at all

```
dojo.toJson("") // returns """" 
dojo.toJson(dijit.byId("XXX").get("value")) //returns ""null""
```

Environment Info: IE 8
Dojo Version: 1.7

Comment: it seems has nothing to do with dijit.form.Form since result is the same when I use dojo.toJson(dijit.byId("Name").get("value")).It's still ""null""

Comment: Yes It has nothing to do with forms. Though I didn't understand your actual question.

Comment: does this code run at the same time the page loads? or in a function? and if you call it in a function when is the function called?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/PsEW8/1/

In either situation the returned value is ""?

Comment: Hi Ricardo Garza V., thanks, it is a function called when button clicked.

Comment: Hi Neel Basu, thanks, the question could be understood as why dojo.toJson(dijit.byId("XXX").get("value")) returns ""null"" while dojo.toJson("") returns """" since dijit.byId("XXX").get("value") is "". This happens only on IE.

Comment: Hi Mschr, thanks, yes, dijit.byId("XXX").get("value") is ""

Answer (score 0):

The output is not `""null""` the extreme first and extreme last quotes are placed by `console.log` these are `"null"` and `""`

and Yes `""` is an empty string which is a string object and is different from `null`.

Comment: thanks, yes, u r right, I should expect "" instead of null, but how does "null" come out? I still don't get it, can u help? thank you very much.